# Convert gaussian function from 3D configuration space into 3D momentum space

Tags: momentum, vectors, fourier-transform

I know, If we convert a gaussian function from 1D position space into 1D momentum space, it will be again a gaussian function. But if we have a gaussian function in a 3D position space, how it will be in the momentum space?
This is my function:
$$ 
f(\vec{r}) = A e^{-ar^2}
$$
I used Fourier transformation:
$$
f(\vec{k})=\iiint e^{-\vec{k}.\vec{r}}{f(\vec{r})}\,d^3r=A\iiint e^{-\vec{k}.\vec{r}}{e^{-ar^2}}r^2 \sin{\theta}\,dr\,d \theta\,d \phi
$$
then:
$$
f(\vec{k})=2\pi A\int_{0} ^{\infty} e^{-ar^2}[\frac{-1}{ikr}e^{-ikr}+\frac{1}{ikr}e^{ikr}]r^2 \,d r=\frac{2\pi A}{ik}\int _{0}^{\infty}[e^{-ar^2+ikr}-e^{-ar^2-ikr}]r \,d r
$$
therefore:
$$
f(\vec{k})=\frac{2 \pi A}{ik}e^{-\frac{k^2}{4a}} \int_0^{\infty}[e^{-a(r-\frac{ik}{2a})^2}-e^{-a(r+\frac{ik}{2a})^2}]r \,d r
$$
but:
$$
\int_0 ^{\infty} e^{-ar^2} r \,d r=\frac{1}{2a}
$$
which makes it equal to zero:
$$
f(\vec{k})=0!!!
$$
where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

A general 3D gaussian is:

$$ f(\vec r) = Ae^{-ax^2} +Be^{-by^2}+Ce^{-cz^2}$$

That will be a 3D gaussian in momentum space with $\sigma_{p_x}\propto 1/a$, $\sigma_{p_y}\propto 1/b$, and $\sigma_{p_z}\propto 1/c$.

Note that:

$$ f(\vec r) = Ae^{-ar^2} = f(r) $$

is a special case with $a=b=c$ and $A=B=C$.

When converting to spherical coordinates, there is no conjugate variable that  is identified as 'radial momentum' with  $\sigma_{p_r}\propto 1/a$.

Where you go wrong is the step where $\exp{i\vec k\cdot\vec r}$ is replaced with $\exp{ikr}$; rather, you must use:

$$e^{i\vec k\cdot\vec r}=4\pi\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-1}^l i^l j_l(kr)Y_l^m({\bf \hat k}){Y_l^m}^*({\bf \hat r})$$

The angular part of the wave is now quantized with $l, m$ describing components of definite angular momentum (and projection on the $z$-axis). The would-be radial plane wave $\exp{ikr}$ is replaced with a spherical wave described by $j_l(kr)$.

If the initial function $f(\vec r)$ is not spherically symmetric, then this proceeds as a standard multipole expansion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion); however, your function has only a monopole moment.

Comment: What happened to the $\cos \theta$ in $e^{{\bf k}\cdot {\bf r}}= e^{ikr \cos \theta}$? You just left it out? The whole calculation is  much easier in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Read the question again. Also: I did the cartesian calculation in the 1st sentence.

Comment: I did not replace $ e^{-i \vec{k}.\vec{r}} $ with $e^{-ikr}$. I supposed $ -i\vec{k}.\vec{r}=-ikr \cos \theta$, then I integrated respect to $\theta$.

Comment: You are correct about the $\cos \theta$. Sorry!  I susect that the probem is the shift in $r$ by the $\pm ik$ is not as harmless as you think. If your $r$ integral was from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$  the shift  would not change anything, but you are intgerating $r$ from $0$ to $\infty$ so you probaly have to worrly abou tthe change of limts on the integral.